# ResNet-101 FeatureMap shape

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, resnet, conv-neural-network

I am really new to CNN and having many troubles with studying it.

I'm trying to extract the CNN feature map using ResNet-101 and I desire to get a shape of 2048, 14*14.
To get a feature map I removed the last layer of ResNet-101 model and adjusted Adaptive Average Pool. So I got `torch.Size([1, 2048, 1, 1])` shape of output.

But I want to get `torch.Size([1, 2048, 14, 14])` not the `torch.Size([1, 2048, 1, 1])`.

Anyone can help me to get the result? Thx.

```
#load resnet101 model and remove the last layer
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.5.0', 'resnet101', pretrained=True)
model = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model.children())[:-1]))


#extract feature map from an image and print the size of the feature map
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from torchvision import transforms

filename = 'KM_0000000009.jpg'
input_image = Image.open(filename)

preprocess = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((244,244)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)

input_tensor = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0) # create a mini-batch as expected by the model

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(input_tensor)

print(output.size()) #torch.Size([1, 2048, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were one step from what you wanted.

First things first - you should always check module's source code (which is located [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/models/resnet.py) for ResNet). It may have some functional operations (e.g. from `torch.nn.functional` module) so it may not be transferable directly to `torch.nn.Seqential`, luckily it is in ResNet101 case.

Secondly, feature maps are dependent on size of the input, for standard ImageNet-like image size (`[3, 224, 224]`, notice your image size is different) there is no layer with shape `[2048, 14, 14]`, but `[2048, 7, 7]` or `[1024, 14, 14]`).

Thirdly, there is no need to use `torch.hub` **for ResNet101** as it uses `torchvision` models under the hood anyway.

With all that in mind:

```
import torch
import torchvision

# load resnet101 model and remove the last layer
model = torchvision.models.resnet101()
model = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model.children())[:-3]))

# image-like
image = torch.randn(1, 3, 224, 224)

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(image)

print(output.size())  # torch.Size([1, 1024, 14, 14])
```

If you would like `[2048, 7, 7]` use `[:-2]` instead of `[:-3]`.
Also, you can notice below how the feature map size changes with image shape:

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(*(list(model.children())[:-2]))  
# Image twice as big -> twice as big height and width of features!
image = torch.randn(1, 3, 448, 448)

with torch.no_grad():
    output = model(image)

print(output.size())  # torch.Size([1, 2048, 14, 14])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transforms.CenterCrop(224)
```

change 224 to 448 will make it from [1, 2048, 7, 7] to [1, 2048, 14, 14]